# Is there something wrong with the snippets?

Tags: bug, review, stack-snippets

I posted a question on Code Review. It did not meet the standards and was closed. I asked the same question on Stack Overflow.

While the code in Code Review produces error, the code in Stack Overflow doesn't. The code is the same.

Here are images of the codes:

Code Review:
[image]

Stack Overflow:
[image]

Here are the links to the respective questions:

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255926/javascript-in-searchbar-producing-error)

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66172639/search-bar-doesnt-give-any-result-produces-error-on-some-browsers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, nothing is wrong, in the code of Stack Exchange that is.

There is a difference between your two snippets.

On Code Review:

```
 <!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true babel: null -->
```

On Stack Overflow:

```
 <!-- begin snippet: js hide: true -->
```

Notice how `console: true` is missing.

That setting controls whether your errors show up in the Result pane or can only be found in the [Developer Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) of your favorite browser.

Here is where you can control that *show console* option:

[image: strong text]